# Mirroring Heroku Timeout parameters in local development app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, timeout

I have a rails app that compiles a large set of PDF reports by making calls to salesforce database.

As it's run once in a blue moon I'm hoping I can sneak this in on the Free Tier and convince the holders of purse-strings to upgrade to hobby once I can demonstrate it.

Currently the app works in production but fails (pretty sure it's a `h12`) after a consistent interval when in production on Heroku. This will be because I haven't got around to implementing the heavy lifting as a background-job/delayed-job yet, will follow along [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009519/how-to-increase-heroku-30s-h12-timeout).

I'm new to the background job API, so ideally I'd like to be able to set up RSpec tests and prod around myself with my development app set up to mirror production constraints of the heroku app. So, questions:

1. Should I be trying this? Mirroring  production constraints in my development app seems like a good way to learn and test this stuff locally... but I have an itching idea they're separate for a reason and I'm violating some boundary or missing a more obvious solution (test on production... but locally?)
2. How best to mirror the Heroku production constraints (ideally I'd want to be able to test locally if a process seems to be regularly outstripping a Rack or Puma timeout window or worse going over memory limits (I have some pretty heavy objects in there!) and fail in a comparable way so I can work on how to handle/mitigate such failures.
3. I presume this problem is more universal (constraints of production server differ from dev) than just cos I want to generate PDFs whilst being a cheapskate on Heroku's free tier... does anyone have any good recommendations/reading on best pratice for testing and minimising failures when pushing to production? (I've already run into precompiling assets fun, I'm sure there's other landmines out there somewhere...)

Many thanks!

Comment: You may want to setup a staging instance on heruku which mirrors your production but has its own DB which is cloned with pg_backups on a regular basis. I'm not really familiar with salespoint but it should have a sandbox mode which your staging environment can hit.

Comment: I suppose that would scratch the itch of being able to have a version of the app or sandbox where I can go nuts without worrying that I have a copy of it exposed to the world at my heroku address... I dunno though I kinda liked the idea of being able to run my classic `rails s` and then poke and prod it... Cheers for the advice though I'll look into staging in more depth.

Comment: You can always throw up a simple password wall or proxy around the staging server to protect it from the outside world. Its hard or next to impossible to setup a virtual machine that mirrors heroku as closely.

Comment: True... I guess as the heroku tiers as oft trod and seem to have predictible constraints was hoping someone had the rack equivalent of a dotfile or perhaps a gem recommendation that would be a drop in 'near as damnit' mirroring of their settings...

Comment: For your automated testing however (the tests you write in RSpec or Minitest) you should be using something like Webmock or VCR to fake the interaction with collaborators outside your application. They also let you fake timeouts etc.

Comment: Also a good call, it took me too long to come around to those libraries. The Salesforce API is quick and my calls are ok and well tested so the problems don't appear to be with timeouts to API calls so much as when I draw it all back in and then have to compile everything into many... many... different pdfs...

Answer (score 0):

Running the command `heroku local` seems to get me a good deal of the way there. Docs [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local).

Specifically:

- It can load from my Procfile
- It can load environemntal variables (API keys etc) from the `.env`

If I can set it to mirror the timeouts for the free tier (perhaps in Proc?) I should get me the majority way towards my goal.